# How do I get audio from a ESXI 5.0/5.1 Windows 7 VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, console, esxi

I want to run a LARGE Windows 7/XP VM. Like 50+ Gigabytes of ram and 4 cores. I need to be able to console in to this VM, but for alert purposes I need the VM to pass audio either back out to me via the console connection OR by USB speakers or something. I am on a Lenovo RD530 rack server running a XEON E5 6 core processor. All the info I find on how to do this seems out of date at best, and doesn't work on most. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like VMWare has added the capability to use HD audio. Here is what worked for me.

1. Shut down your virtual machine
2. In vSphere, right-click on the virual machine and select **remove from inventory**
3. Select the root folder in the left panel of vSphere
4. Select the **Configuration tab**
5. Select **Storage**
6. Right-click the datastore where your virtual machine is installed and select **Browse datastore**
7. Open the folder for your virtual machine
8. Right-click on the .vmx file and select **Download**
9. Open the downloaded file in Notepad++
10. At the bottom of the file, add the following:

    ```
    sound.present = "true"
    sound.allowGuestConnectionControl = "false"
    sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
    sound.fileName = "-1"
    sound.autodetect = "true"
    sound.pciSlotNumber = "17"
    ```

**Note:** Select an available pciSlotNumber. Review all of the PCI slots being used in your .vmx file, and select a slot number that is not currently being used.

11. In the VMWare datastore, select **upload files to this virtual machine**, select the .vmx file, and upload it
12. Right-click on the .vmx file, select **Add to Inventory**, and select Next, Next, Finish to add the virtual machine to inventory
13. In the left panel of vSphere, right-click on the virtual machine and select **Edit Settings**
14. In the virual machine dialog box, on the Hardware tab, there should now be an option HD audio

Boot the virtual machine. In the screen shot below, I am using a Linux CentOS virtual machine. Instead of CentOS outputing sound to Dummy Audio, CentOS is now output audio to HD Audio Controller.

[image]

Comment: But he’s not using VMWare!

Answer (score 1):

On VMWare Workstation, a USB device gets plugged into the guest, as far as it can tell.
If ESXi works the same way (I expect it *does*, just might be more formal about provisioning it) then a USB sound device ought to work.  If it shows up under "Sound, vided and game controllers" that ought to work.

⋯yes, hardware version 7 or higher, noted in a manual for an older version.  Also see references to USB3 being added at some point.